# Storing player specific data

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm working on a bukkit plugin and I need to save data when the player quits. I wrote a system which works fine but it's based on the player's name and if the player changes their name it will lose the data. So my question is this: Is there any property (ex.: an id) witch is the same every time the player logs in?

Comment: [First google result](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20minecraft%20get%20player%20id) : [Moving from Player Names to UUID.](https://forums.bukkit.org/threads/tut-moving-from-player-names-to-uuid.241626/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the player's `UUID`, or **U**niversally **U**nique **ID**entifier. To get the player's `UUID`, you could use `player.getUniqueId()`. You can also do it with `OfflinePlayers`.

An example method for storing when a player quits via their `UUID` would be:

```
@EventHandler
public void playerQuit(PlayerQuitEvent e){
    String uuid = e.getPlayer().getUniqueId().toString(); // get the user's UUID
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000; // get the current number of seconds
    plugin.getConfig().set(uuid, time); // set the UUID in the config to the current # of seconds
}
```

Then, to get the day they last played:

```
public Date getLastPlayedDate(String p){
    String uuid = Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(p).getUniqueId().toString(); // get the uuid from the OfflinePlayer
    long time = plugin.getConfig().getLong(uuid); // get the time associated with the uuid
    Date date = new Date(time * 1000); // convert the time to the date
    return date; // return the date
}
```

Comment: Note: `UUID` stands for __Universally Unique Identifier__ instead.

Comment: @Unihedron It can stand for many things. Most of the time when using Minecraft players, though, it's *Universal User Identifier*, because it's only dealing with users. If we were doing something like Minecraft mobs, it would be a *Universally Unique Identifier*, because we aren't doing anything with users.

Comment: __Universally Unique Identifier__ is the term coined by and setforth by the OSF. If you can point me to a resource which clearly states what you just said it would be amazing. Otherwise, [here's the wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).